# SQL Server: when it's neccessary to use functions/procedures and not queries?

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I started to learn functions and stored procedures in Microsoft SQL Server and noticed that everything that they do also can be done with a queries. I'm sure, they exist for a reason, so I'd like to ask:

1. What can be done using functions / procedures that's impossible to do with a query?
2. In which cases one should use procedures/functions and not queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing *magic* about functions or procedures - there's nothing you cannot do in an ad-hoc query as well.

They can be used to **reuse** some code - write the function **once** and use it everywhere, instead of writing the same T-SQL code over and over and over again.

And they can be used to combine code that belongs together (like withdraw amount x from account #1 and deposit it into account #2) into a single, reusable procedure which can also handle transactions internally.

So basically: nothing magic - but using functions and procedures (like in any other programming language) can help **reuse** and centralize some code, and make your life easier

Comment: Good Explanation, Really Helpful :) Thank You.